# Absolutely-positioned element changes position when I toggle the CSS rule in Chrome devtools off and then on again

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a Vue.js project where a particular element that has its `position` set to `absolute` is not showing up in the right place when the page first loads, but if I just turn the CSS rule off and then on again, it then shows up in the right place.

Has anyone seen this kind of issue before?

---

Here's what it looks like when the page first renders:

[image]

---

Here's where I toggle the CSS rule:

- (I can toggle either the `position` rule or the `right` rule and either will make the element start showing up in the correct place.)

[image]

---

Here it is in the correct position after I turn the CSS rule off and then on again:

[image]

---

Another way that the positioning can be fixed is if I *don't* toggle the CSS rule, but instead just navigate to another route that uses a different icon on the right side of the navbar, and then navigate back to a route that uses that 'watch' icon.  The 'watch' icon will then show up in the right place.

Comment: can you paste a working code snippet or provide a jsfiddle/slackblitz demo?

Comment: @AkhiAkl It's a complicated, Webpacked app, so it won't be easy to create a jsfiddle demo.  I was hoping to hear from people who have seen this issue before.  I'll consider trying to make a jsfiddle once I finish the other work I need to do on this app.

Comment: @NathanWailes try to set `top` as well like `top:20px` and just use class selector like `.filter_menu` as its good practice to style with the class only.

Comment: @Awais Good idea, that got rid of the issue.  I don't know why I didn't think to do that.  I'll leave this question open since it's still strange that it was behaving like that.

Comment: No @NathanWailes its not strange issue its browser's Css rending issue and also if you don't specify top, left and other attributes, they are inherited from parent element, or are set by defaults in browser's css.

Comment: @Awais I understand that; what I find strange is that toggling a CSS rule off and then on again would change the position of the element.

Comment: @NathanWailes as you do that in inspector, in which there is no browser rendering(its static), or you can say that when toggle off and on it takes its first parent styles so it will come to its right place without `top`

Comment: @Awais I'm not sure I understand.  Why would the inheritance behavior of the styling change after the page has been rendered?  I have never seen Vue cause a styling bug like this before.